# Set an object to nil after added them to a container?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsset

I thought that `NSArray`/`NSDictionary`/`NSSet` and their mutable subclasses just added the pointer to the object, and not the object it self.

So if set my "simple" object to nil after I added it to the container, why isn't the reference nil also in the Array (container)?

**Here is the code:**

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Simple *simple = [[Simple alloc] init];
[array addObject:simple];

//Array sends retain, lets release
[simple release], simple = nil;

NSLog(@"Simple = \"<Simple: %p>", simple);
NSLog(@"Array: %@", array);

[array release], array = nil;
```

**Here is the output:**

```
2011-02-16 20:00:03.149 Allocations[5433:207] Simple = <Simple: 0x0>
2011-02-16 20:00:03.150 Allocations[5433:207] Array: (
    <Simple: 0x4d3d4e0>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSArray adds a pointer to the *object*. In order to track changes to variable, the array would have to add a pointer to **the variable itself** (remember, you're just setting the variable to nil, not the object). There can be many variables all pointing to the same object, and reassigning them won't change any others.

Remember: Pointers aren't magic. They're just ordinary variables whose value is a memory address — in this case, the memory address of an object. Two pointers to the same object aren't "linked" any more than two `int`s with the value `5`. Changing the pointer doesn't affect the object; in order to affect the object, you have to either send it a message that causes it to change (e.g. `[object setValue:6]`) or *dereference the pointer* to access the object's members directly (e.g. `object->value = 6`).

<sub>PS: Don't access an object's members directly. It's bad and fragile and very prone to bugs. I just mentioned it here to explain how pointers work.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Setting simple = nil just makes that pointer point to nothing. It doesn't delete the object that the array still has a pointer to. At the point of your NSLog statements, the retainCount of the Simple instance that simple pointed to would be one.

Create simple

- simple => (Simple instance: retain count 1)

Add to array

- simple => (Simple instance: retain count 2)
- [array objectAtIndex:0] => (Simple instance: retain count 2)

Release simple

- simple => (Simple instance: retain count 1)
- [array objectAtIndex:0] => (Simple instance: retain count 1)

Set simple = nil

- simple => nil
- [array objectAtIndex:0] => (Simple instance: retain count 1)

Release array

- (Simple instance: retain count 0, subsequently destroyed)

Comment: Do not think of retain counts as an absolute number.  It is a delta;  you increase or decrease it.   The `retainCount` method is useless.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` does contain only a pointer to the object that is added, but that's ok -- it's not pointing to the `simple` pointer itself, but rather to the `Simple` object that `simple` pointed to. Thus in your example, after you change what `simple` points to, the array is still pointing at the original `Simple` object.